Synapse Docker instance cannot see Postgres instance
I'm attempting to substitute Postgres for SQLite on an ARM machine, to provide the backend for a Synapse instance.
I first attempted to create a simple docker network (matrix) to allow inter-container communication, with the following docker-compose:
version: '3'

services:
  matrix:
    container_name: synapse
    image: matrixdotorg/synapse:latest
    ports:
      - "8008:8008"
      - "8448:8448"
    volumes:
      - ./synapsedata:/data
    environment:
      - SYNAPSE_SERVER_NAME=<url>
      - SYNAPSE_REPORT_STATS=no
      - POSTGRES_DB=<db>
      - POSTGRES_HOST=db
      - POSTGRES_USER=<user>
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<password>
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks: ["matrix"]
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<password>
      - POSTGRES_DB=<db>
      - POSTGRES_USER=<user>
      - POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS=--encoding="UTF8" --lc-collate="C" --lc-ctype="C"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks: ["matrix"]
volumes:
  synapse-data:
  postgres-data:
networks:
  matrix:

When I then docker network inspect matrix_matrix, the postgres machine is reported as being on the matrix network at 172.18.0.2. However, in homeserver.yaml, I had the postgres host set to matrix - which instead resolved to 172.18.0.3.
I then attempted to statically assign IP addresses with the following networks config:
networks:
  matrix:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.18.0.0/16

setting the IP of the postgres machine manually to 172.18.0.2 and the synapse machine to 172.18.0.3. I then set the postgres host in homeserver.yaml to 172.18.0.2.
However, the connection to the postgres server still fails:
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "178.18.0.2", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Should I be doing something else with the docker configuration, or is this an issue with synapse itself? Postgres is running normally.
